# .htaccess not working for redirect subfolder to apache root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm on Debian 8 and I have a website in http://my-domain.unice.fr/social and I want to redirect this on http://my-domain.unice./

In my .htaccess I have :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^social/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and in my apache2.conf :

```
</Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But when I going to my domain, I have the list of my file/folder in my root directory ... and not my website.

What I forgot in my config ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a spelling mistake：

wrong: `AllowOvveride All`

correct: `AllowOverride All`

Comment: It's a keybard error when I typed my message. Sorry.

In my apache2.conf, it's AllowOverride All